# List(i : j) gives me a list of size 1 when i-j > 1

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function that returns an nxn matrix with has values of row index -column index for each of its elements.

e.g.

```
n = 3
0 -1 -2
1 0  -1
2 1  0
```

```cs
ijMatrix <- function(n) {
  temp <- list()
  for (i in 0 : -(n - 1)) {
    temp2 <- list(i : i + n - 1) #issue
    temp[length(temp) + 1] <- temp2 
  }
  temp
}
  
print(ijMatrix(3))
```

The issue that I'm encountering is that when the line marked "issue" is reached, I want to create a list that has the values from i to i + n - 1, but I get a list with only one value. For example, if i = 0 and n = 3, then I should get a list {0,1,2}. However, I'm only getting 2. I also would like to preserve the "style" of this function and would not like to use a completely different method to create the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numeric vectors, not lists, and cbind the results together:

```
ijMatrix <- function(n) {
  temp <- c()
  for (i in 0 : -(n - 1)) {
    temp2 <- i : (i + n - 1)
    temp <- cbind(temp, temp2)
  }
  dimnames(temp) <- NULL # remove column names
  temp
}

ijMatrix(3)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    0   -1   -2
## [2,]    1    0   -1
## [3,]    2    1    0
```

Even easier is

```
row(diag(3)) - col(diag(3))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    0   -1   -2
## [2,]    1    0   -1
## [3,]    2    1    0
```

or

```
outer(1:3, 1:3, `-`)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    0   -1   -2
## [2,]    1    0   -1
## [3,]    2    1    0
```